# why isn't changeColor() called when I do animation.start()?

Tags: python, pyqt6

I have this code:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import *

class FadeItem(QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.animation = QVariantAnimation()
        self.animation.setStartValue(QColor.fromRgb(193, 0, 193))
        self.animation.setEndValue(QColor.fromRgb(193, 0, 193, 0))
        self.animation.setDuration(300)
        self.animation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.InBack)
        self.animation.valueChanged.connect(self.changeColor)
    
    def changeColor(self, color):
        print(color)
        self.setBackground(color)

    def startFade(self):
        self.animation.stop()
        self.animation.start()
```

What I want is when I add an element to the table I call `startFade()` and the background of the cell should fade from purple to white. But when I call `startFade()`, `changeColor()` is never called.

If I add this function

```
    def startAnimation(self):
        self.startFade()
        loop = QEventLoop()
        self.animation.finished.connect(loop.quit)
        loop.exec()
```

it works, the `changeColor()` function get called and the background fade, the only problem is that it blocks the execution of the entire program.




Edit:
the problem was that I was calling startFade() from another Thread.

Comment: I have no certainty about PySide6, but with PyQt there are only rare exceptions for which you can actually use multiple inheritance from two *Qt* classes. Besides, it's unclear why you want to inherit from QObject, since the only requirement I see in your code is the parent argument of the animation, which is unnecessary as long as its reference is persistent; you also never called the `__init__` of the QObject super class, so, technically, the code above should not even work. I suggest you to completely remove that inheritance and that `self` parent argument for the animation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I added QObject after trying without it, it change nothing.

Comment: Then remove it as it's unnecessary (and wrong), and provide a comprehensive [mre], because without the QObject inheritance your code should work.

Comment: I removed the QObject inheritance, as I said before it changed nothing

Comment: We're still waiting for a MRE.

Comment: while I was writing the MRE i found out that you can't call startFade() from another Thread